# State whether the given set is a closed or open?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the space $X = \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ of real valued functions on $[0,1]$ given the product topology. Determine whether the following subsets of $X$ is closed or not.

1. The subset consisting of all continuous functions.
2. The subset consisting of functions that take integer values everywhere.

My attempt:

Option a is not closed. Consider the sequence of function $\{f_k(x)=x^k\}$ in $X$. Its limit is a $f(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $1$ otherwise which is not a continuous function.

Please help how to solve the option 2. The  answer given is that it is a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be in the complementary of this set, denoted by $A$. Then, there exists a value $x_0\in [0,1]$ with $f(x_0)$ which is not an integer. Let $U_{\epsilon}=\{g\in X,\ |g(x_0)-f(x_0)|\leq \epsilon\}$. If $\epsilon$ is small enough, then $g(x_0)$ cannot be an integer for any $g$ in $U_\epsilon$, i.e. $U_\epsilon$ is included in $A$. As $U_\epsilon$ is open by definition of the product topology, we have the conclusion.